# Know any hardware for the PC to act as USB_device?

Tags: usb, development-tools

We manufacture electronic devices. Some of them has USB_host functionality. In order to test them for this functionality, we need another device (maybe pseudo device like PC) to act as the USB_device. Currently, we only support MassStorage class devices but we are not comfortable with the idea of inserting a USB memory to our device for Q/C operation. There won't be any feedback to our automation system and we want to be able to test other kind of devices.

Is there some kind of hardware that we plug into a PC and with its certain API, that device acts as a USB_device. We will have to implement the needed protocol by utilizing this API and we are OK with this.

Any chance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Facedancer](http://travisgoodspeed.blogspot.com/2012/07/emulating-usb-devices-with-python.html) lets you emulate USB devices with host-side Python code.

[image: Facedancer]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to test the mass storage mode, your best bet may be an embedded linux board with a USB device interface, and using the gadget file storage kernel module.  If you cannot derive sufficient information from its log output, you can always modify the source code to instrument it with extra reporting.

It's possible the board might be capable of running your entire test apparatus, if not, you'll need to use some other interface such as ethernet or a serial port to report back to your main testing computer.

For a simpler setup, almost every USB-capable microcontroller has a mass storage reference design / code example available.  And most have a serial port which you could use (possibly via a USB-serial converter) for reporting results back to the main testing computer.

If you want more detailed quality metrics than works/doesn't work, you'll probably need a USB bus analyzer, either by itself or inline to monitor interaction with a microcontroller or embedded-linux based mass storage emulating device.

Answer (score 0):

For Q/C you want to anticipate any environmental stress your product will see and look for defects that may be acclerated by those stress factors. It may have failed already simply due to solder. Those are easy to find. I suggest in addition to USB device emulation you consider some HASS testing as well to include vibration, lower voltage margin as well as fault injection.

As for simulation the USB interface specs worst case timing could be applied.

I cant vouch for any direct USB emulation experience here, just TE/QA test philosphy.
A crossover cable can  connect USB to USB but emulation depends on which functions give the biggest fault coverage for devices that you want to emaulate. If the design was thoroughly tested (DVT) then mechanical flaws may be all you need to test.  [Ref](http://www.fored.co.uk/html/usb_library.html)